# JNI Error: com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, bluetooth, registry, jna, advapi32

I'm using JNA 4.2.1 to access Windows Registry from Java (unfortunately it's only way to get the list of paired Bluetooth devices). It was working okay, until Windows 10 has installed some updates, now I have the following problem:

> com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the
>   file specified.   at
>   com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util.registryGetValues(Advapi32Util.java:1649)
>     at IntelleWave.Devices.Device.getCOMportByBTUID(Device.java:243)    at
>   IntelleWave.Devices.Device.getBTDeviceInstances(Device.java:163)  at
>   IntelleWave.Devices.Device.getDeviceInstances(Device.java:112)    at
>   IntelleWave.Devices.Device.(Device.java:72)     at
>   IntelleWave.Devices.DeviceEnumerator.InitDevices(DeviceEnumerator.java:101)
>     at
>   IntelleWave.SettingsScreenController.UpdateDeviceList(SettingsScreenController.java:662)
>     at
>   IntelleWave.SettingsScreenController.initialize(SettingsScreenController.java:153)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)    at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)     at
>   IntelleWave.ScreensController.loadScreen(ScreensController.java:46)
>     at IntelleWave.IntelleWave.init(IntelleWave.java:175)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:841)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

For me it looks strange that I see Win32 Exception but in fact I have a Windows 64. Maybe problem related to that difference and I have to tell JNI to use x64 library (Advapi32Util)?

could you please advice.

Comment: Finally I decided to look around and found very interesting post dedicated to the task how to use WinReg from JAVA.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java - I'm going to try most voted options than share results here.

Comment: The "win32" APIs exist on both 32- and 64-bit windows.